# spring cloud consul will replace . to - before registering

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-consul

I'm using spring cloud consul to register my service, but it will always replace the . to - before registering, like this:

My application name: `com.test.app`

The name in consul: `com-test-app`

I tried the `spring.application.name` & `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.service-name`, they're the same.

anyone knows how to avoid this convertion?

Thank you very much.

=======================================

Updated on Jun 23, 2017:

I've tried to use curl to register to consul, it supports this, so I guess it's the convertion is a spring cloud limitation, please help!

```
    pansion@server ~ -> curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/register -d '{ "ID": "test_001", "Name":"com.test.app", "Address": "10.0.0.10", "Port": 8080 }'
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100    81    0     0  100    81      0     81  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01 81000
    pansion@server ~ ->
    pansion@server ~ -> curl 127.0.0.1:8500/v1/catalog/services
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100    45  100    45    0     0     45      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01 45000{
        "com.test.app": [],
        "consul": []
    }

    pansion@server ~ ->
    pansion@server ~ -> curl 127.0.0.1:8500/v1/catalog/service/com.test.app
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   551  100   551    0     0  36733      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 36733[
        {
            "ID": "3789117d-a44e-c82b-07dd-b386a1f2eeef",
            "Node": "server",
            "Address": "127.0.0.1",
            "Datacenter": "dc1",
            "TaggedAddresses": {
                "lan": "127.0.0.1",
                "wan": "127.0.0.1"
            },
            "NodeMeta": {},
            "ServiceID": "test_001",
            "ServiceName": "com.test.app",
            "ServiceTags": [],
            "ServiceAddress": "10.0.0.10",
            "ServicePort": 8080,
            "ServiceEnableTagOverride": false,
            "CreateIndex": 12,
            "ModifyIndex": 12
        }
    ]

    pansion@server ~ ->
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically the service name should not contain dots or periods,Please refer the [documentation](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/services.html)

***DNS-compliant service and tag names may contain any alpha-numeric characters, as well as dashes. Dots are not supported because Consul internally uses them to delimit service tags.***

Comment: Thank you for replying.
But the consul rest API can support that, for example, this works:
  curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/register -d '{ "ID": "test_001", "Name":"com.test.app", "Address": "10.0.0.10", "Port": 8080 }'

Comment: This is PUT, what is the response you are getting in GET? It will internally convert that DOT

Comment: Thanks, updated the curl response in the original post.